# snap svg animate to original size and position

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, snap.svg

When user hover the baloon svg, I want to animate baloon svg (make it bigger).
And when the user unhover the baloon, baloon will return to its original size.
I use this to reset it to original size and position.

```
transform: 's1'
```

It work in chrome, firefox, safari.
But when I tried it on IE, the expand animation work, but the reset animation doesn't work, it blinked to original size without animation.

```
$baloonColumn.on('mouseenter', function() {
    animateExpandBaloon();
});

$baloonColumn.on('mouseleave', function() { 
    animateNormalBaloon();  
});

var animateExpandBaloon = function() {
    baloonShout.animate({
        transform: 's1.1T5,10'
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);

    baloon.animate({
        transform: 's1.05T'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonRightEye.animate({
        transform: 's1T3,-2'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonLeftEye.animate({
        transform: 's1T3,-2'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonTail.animate({
        transform: 's1T15,0'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonMouth.animate({
        transform: 's1.15T'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);
}

var animateNormalBaloon = function() {
    baloonShout.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 1000, mina.elastic);

    baloon.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic); 

    baloonRightEye.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonLeftEye.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonTail.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);

    baloonMouth.animate({
        transform: 's1'
    }, 1200, mina.elastic);
}
```

How should be the element animated to original size and position correctly?

Comment: I think realistically you will probably need to provide a jsfiddle with a basic bit of code highlighting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i think You shoud use Snap hover function;
http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.hover

I was doing kinda same thing im pretty sure, and i found my way through this by setting custom attributes of elements i animated. I needed many different states and that may not be the most elegant solution, but it works, and svg specs does allow setting custom attributes on paths.
Since i was setting transforms my svg data dynamically, i was able to set attrs on creation.

So, how it came;

```
element.attr('state-static',my-static-state-string);
```

And then;

```
element.hover(
    function(){
        element.animate('transform':'T15,0');
    },function(){
        element.animate('transform':element.attr('state-static'));
    })
```

Let me know if this helped You